# Codeigniter - Dependent Select Box with database

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, codeigniter

i'm just wanna ask again about codeigniter.

I want to make dependent select form in codeigniter with sql server database.

I have an database table name `MS_UPB` (it contains a location) and `MS_RUANG` (it contains a room in that location). **My task is to show the room where the `MS_RUANG.kd_lokasi` (this is the room location ID) = `MS_UP.kd_lokasi` (this is the location ID) and show it in the dependent select box codeigniter**

My Views:

```
<?php
echo form_open('admin/laporan/tampildbr',$att)
?>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Unit Kerja</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <select name="unit" id="unit">
                <?php
                foreach ($isdata as $row) {
                    echo "<option value='".$row->KDUPB."|".$row->NAMAUPB."'>".$row->NAMAUPB."</option>";
                }
                ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Ruangan</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <select name="ruangan" id="ruangan" id="ruangan_label">
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Jenis</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="radio" name="jenis" value="DAFTAR BARANG RUANGAN" />Daftar Barang ruangan
            </div>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="radio" name="jenis" value="REKAP DBR" />Rekap DBR
            </div>
        </div>

            <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">   
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" formtarget="_blank">Kirim</button>
            </div>
            </div>
            </form>
           <p>&nbsp;</p>
           <p>&nbsp;</p>

<?php form_close();?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#ruangan,#ruangan_label').hide();
$('#unit').change(function(){
    var unit_id = $('#unit').val();
    if (unit_id != ""){
        var post_url = "admin/laporan/getruangan" + unit_id;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
             url: post_url,
             success: function(ruangan) //what's this ruangan mean?
              {
                $('#ruangan').empty();
                $('#ruangan, #ruangan_label').show();
                   $.each(ruangan,function(kd_ruang,ruang) 
                   {
                    var opt = $('<option />');
                      opt.val(kd_ruang);
                      opt.text(ruang);
                      $('#ruangan').append(opt); 
                    });
               } //end success
         }); //end AJAX
    } else {
        $('#ruangan').empty();
        $('#ruangan, #ruangan_label').hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

My Controller:

```
function getruangan($unit)
    {
        $unit=explode('|',$unit);
        $unitkerja=$unit[0];
        $this->load->model('admin/laporanmodel','',TRUE);
        header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');
        echo (json_encode($this->laporanmodel->get_ruangan($unitkerja)));
    }
```

My Model:

```
function get_ruangan($unit)
    {
        $this->db->select('kd_ruang,namaruang');
        $this->db->from('MS_RUANG');
        $this->db->where('kd_lokasi, "'.$unit.'"');
        $query=$this->db->get();
        $ruangan=array();
        if($query->result()){
            foreach ($query->result() as $ruang) {
                $ruangan[$ruang->kd_ruang] = $ruang->kd_ruang;
            }
            return $ruangan;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

please help me, thanks for your help :)

Comment: what is the error you are getting now?? not getting appended properly??

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju The return value doesn't appear in the view

Comment: check my answer. You have a mistake in your append part.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have issue while appending the value to your select box.

I would tell you to do all required stuff in model itself. If you do so, we can **`reduce execution time of one for loop`**

Try changing in your model like this.

**In Model**

```
if($query->result()){
    $option = "<option>Select the value</option>";// this is for default value.
    foreach ($query->result() as $ruang) {
        $ruangan[$ruang->kd_ruang] = $ruang->kd_ruang;
        $option .= "<option value='$ruang->kd_ruang'>{$ruang->kd_ruang}</option>".
    }
    return $option;
} else {
    return FALSE;
}
```

In model only we are generating required html for our view.

**In Controller**

```
//header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');// comment this line
echo ($this->laporanmodel->get_ruangan($unitkerja));
```

I have removed `json` part in controller. We will take plain text here.

**In view**

Im changing entire `success()` in ajax,

```
success: function(ruangan) //what's this ruangan mean?
{
    $('#ruangan').append(ruangan);// just append the value coming from ajax call here.        
}
```

We have reduced execution time of one loop.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @YogaBayuAjiPranawa keep `alert(ruangan)` in `success()` and see what its alerting.

Comment: Then there is an error in ajax call... see the console if you have any error.

Comment: It says 500 (Internal Server Error)